# Antd table - sorting by a value other than dataIndex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need Query Params String to send other value than dataIndex as sort parameter value. For example, my column looks like this:

```
{
  key: 'id',
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  fixed: 'left',
  sorter: true
},
```

I need to send sort parameter="nameId", but I can't change `dataIndex`, how can I do that? I can't find information about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this

```
{
  key: 'id',
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'nameId',
  fixed: 'left',
  sorter: true
},
```

Comment: I can't change dataIndex because this is how data is matched to the table (BE returns id and takes nameId as sort)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head), you can add `sorter: (a, b) => a.nameId - b.nameId,` to your columns object, then you can sort the table by nameId by clicking the "Name"

```
{
  key: 'name',
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  fixed: 'left',
  sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
},
```

Comment: Still, "id" is sending in query params. I created a simple sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hofstadter-wo1sj?file=/src/App.js . See console.log - I probably have to send columnKey "nameId" without changing dataIndex

Comment: your data doesn't have "nameId" field, so if you want to sort by name you can try like:
{
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  },